# Basic jQuery Ajax file upload with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I've been trying to get a basic file upload through an ajax form without success. I'm looking for the bare minimum basics and nothing I have found through searching has worked.

I've been messing about with this for about 8 hours and have tried at least a dozen different methods but have not been able to get anything successfully uploaded.

I have narrowed down my code to the most bare necessities as best I can.

My JavaScript goes like this:

```
function uploadFile(param) { //Upload File
          $.ajax({
            url: "modules/upload/upload.php",
            type: "post",
            data: new FormData($(param)[0]),
              cache: false,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
          });
}
```

which is called with:

```
$(".app-canvas").on('change', ".fileUpload", function () {
uploadFile($(this));
});
```

and the PHP:

```
<?php
$sourcePath = $_FILES['driver_licence_image']['tmp_name'];       // Storing source path of the file in a variable
$targetPath = "uploads/".$_FILES['driver_licence_image']['name']; // Target path where file is to be stored
move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath) ;    // Moving Uploaded file
?>
```

Comment: what errors are you seeing? is your php code executing?

Comment: yes, the php is executing and not returning any errors

Comment: Let try to set ajax header is 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'

Answer (score 0):

FormData takes an HTMLFormElement as an argument to its constructor, you're passing what looks a file input. To add a file from a form element you have to use `append`.

```
$(".app-canvas").on('change', ".fileUpload", uploadFile);

function uploadFile() { //Upload File
      var fd = new FormData();
      fd.append('driver_licence_image', this.files[0]);
      $.ajax({
        url: "modules/upload/upload.php",
        type: "post",
        data: fd,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
}
```

p.s. `$(param)[0]` is equivalent to `param`(when param is a dom node), so please don't do that.

Comment: Cannot read property '0' of undefined.

The param is supposed to be the file upload input <input class="fileUpload" id="driver_licence_image" type="file" name="driver_licence_image">

Comment: I changed the way you attach the event handler, so that the context will be the file input